# How to show specific object from JSON on specific page?

Tags: react-native

I have a list of names pulled from json that im iterating through and posting on PersonList page. I want to click onto a specific persons 'View Profile' button, it'll redirect to their PersonShow

im calling the data as the variable 'persons'.

PersonList page . - iterating through json and printing each person to a list.  On 'View Profile' it should go to the unique persons list.

```
getPersons() {  
 return persons.filter(person => {  
 return person;  
});
let persons;
    persons = this.getPersons().map((person, id) => {
      return (
        <View
          key={id}
          }}
        >
      <Text>{person.name}</Text>
            <Button
              title={'View Profile'}
              key={id}
              onPress={() =>
                this.props.navigation.navigate('PersonShow', {
                  personId: `${person.id}`,
                })} </Button>
```

PersonShow Page.  it should have the person.name of the specific person im referencing on view profile

```
render() {
    person = persons.map((person, id) => {
      key = { id };
      person => person.id === this.props.navigation.state.params.personId;
    });
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {persons.name}
```

Comment: can you send a data for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass `person` object to `PersonShow` page in `onPress` function:

```
onPress={() =>
    this.props.navigation.navigate('PersonShow', {
      person
})}
```

In `PersonShow` page you can get the `person` object by navigation param as below:

```
render() {
    let person = this.props.navigation.state.params.person;
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>
                    {persons.name}
                    ..
```

Comment: Correct. Thanks my friend.  i knew i was making it too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

• While on PersonList page, you can save the name of the Person in browser cookies when user clicks "View Profile" button.

• Then you can just redirect to PersonShow page and within that page you show up the value stored in cookies by the previous page.

HTML is stateless. You need some kind of memory to store the specific portion of the whole JSON as you let the user redirect to a new page. Using browser cookies is one way of storing that data. Javascript can read and write to browser cookies.

If cookies are disabled in your browser, then you will have to use a server side script written in JAVA, PHP, C# , etc.. to remember the person name, as you let the user go to PersonShow page.